# OAEP padding for OpenSSL

Tags: rsa, openssl

I'm trying to decrypt a file using a private RSA key using OpenSSL. It keeps giving me the same 3 errors that I believe can be solved by adding oaep padding to it. What is the syntax for adding the oaep padding? My current code is: `openssl rsautl -decrypt -in out.enc -out decrypted_message.txt -inkey private.pem` Where out.enc is the encrypted file and private.pem is the private key. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For OAEP with all default parameters (label hash = SHA1 and data = empty, MGF = MGF1 with SHA1) `rsautl -decrypt` (or `-encrypt`) has an option `-oaep` -- see the help message or the man page on your system (unless nonWSL Windows) [or the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/rsautl.html). For other parameters assuming 1.0.2 up use instead:

```
openssl pkeyutl -encrypt|-decrypt [-in $file] [-out $file] \
  [-inkey rsapub.pem -pubin | -inkey rsapriv.pem] -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep \
  [-pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:$hash] [-pkeyopt rsa_oaep_label:$hex] [-pkeyopt rsa_mgf1_md:$hash]
```